# Toggle.slide.right Do not work properly on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Toggle right do not work as needed in mobile version, it appears from center. It is ok in full version for desktops.
Example: https://streamable.com/eiy8c

```js
$("#buttonStart").click(function() {
  {
    $('#content101').toggle('slide', {
      direction: 'right'
    }, 500);
  }
});

$("#buttonClose").click(function() {
  {
    $('#content101').toggle('slide', {
      direction: 'right'
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="buttonStart">
<input id="buttonClose">
<div id="content101">
  Content
</div>
```

I tried toggle left and it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use animate() function instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '250px'});
      });
    });
    </script> 
    </head>
    <body>

    <button>Start Animation</button>

    <p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>

    <div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, using animate() function instead toggle() solve my question, but may be you know, why toggle.right do not work properly on mobile platforms?

Comment: Sorry mate. I don't have grip on mobile platform.

Answer (score -1):

Drop the ID's approach and try toggle them by their class. See if its working

Comment: thank you for reply, but that doesn't solve the problem.